# Java using PostMethod multiple times

Tags: java

I found a example of Java PostMethod [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/HttppostmethodExample.htm).

But I want to post several times by using for loop. I made it like this.

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PostMethodExample {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Test Client");

    BufferedReader br = null;

    PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://search.yahoo.com/search");
    method.addParameter("p", "\"java2s\"");

    try{
            String[] parameters = { "Google", "Yahoo", "MSN" };

            for (String s in parameters){
                int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
                method.addParameter("p", s);
                if(returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
                    System.err.println("The Post method is not implemented by this URI");
                    // still consume the response body
                    method.getResponseBodyAsString();
                } else {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
                    String readLine;
                    while(((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                        System.err.println(readLine);
                    }
                }
                method.releaseConnection();
                method = new PostMethod("http://search.yahoo.com/search");
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println(e);
    } finally {
      method.releaseConnection();
      if(br != null) try { br.close(); } catch (Exception fe) {}
    }
  }
}
```

I modified code just inside of `try` block. I don't think this is the best way. Help me to improve this code.

Comment: for (String s in parameters)? Is it supposed to compile? And don't swallow exceptions, report them.

Comment: While `System.err.println(e)` isn't really swallowing an exception, it's not really reporting it properly either. If you must print somewhere instead of logging, at least use `e.printStackTrace()`

Comment: I don't think you want to modify the inside of the `try` block, as you've effectively prevented the finally block from releasing each connection you're attempting.

Answer (score 6):

**Avoid catching all exceptions**

Do not use `catch (Exception e)` as this will also catch `NullPointerException`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` and a whole lot of other ones. **Only catch the Exceptions you need to catch**, such as `IOException`. It is said that one should [be specific in throws clause](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=27), but that applies for **catch** as well.

And as stated in the comments to your question, `System.err.println(e)` does not give full information about the exception. If you don't have a logger system nearby that can handle exceptions completely, at least use `e.printStackTrace();`. It is however recommended that you should *handle* and exception, and not only *report* it. For example by displaying a more accurate error message to the user.

Also, I would say that your line `if(br != null) try { br.close(); } catch (Exception fe) {}` should be on multiple lines. Even if it increases line count, it improves readability.

```
if (br != null) {
    try {
       br.close();
    }
    catch (Exception fe) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this pattern of creating an instance, running it through the loop, and at the end of the loop re-initializing it, is a bad one. This case is a good example of what can go wrong... because you have introduced a bug as a result

The first time through the loop your `method` is configured as:

```
PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://search.yahoo.com/search");
method.addParameter("p", "\"java2s\"");
```

but for the remaining loop iterations the `method` is simply:

```
method = new PostMethod("http://search.yahoo.com/search");
```

Similarly, another bug that has 'creeped' (crept?) in is you change the 'p' parameter **after** the request is posted....

```
int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
method.addParameter("p", s);
```

There is no reason, in this case, why you can't initialize the `method` inside the loop, it makes more sense, and you eliminate bugs....:

```
for (String s in parameters){

    final PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://search.yahoo.com/search");
    method.addParameter("p", s);
    int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);

    ....

    method.releaseConnection();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I find your indentation a bit strange. You have two-space indentation in one place, and eight-space in another. Keep it consistent.

Java conventions recommend four-space indents.

```
public class PostMethodExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.getParams().setParameter("http.useragent", "Test Client");

        BufferedReader br = null;

        PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://search.yahoo.com/search");
        method.addParameter("p", "\"java2s\"");

        try{
            String[] parameters = { "Google", "Yahoo", "MSN" };

            for (String s in parameters){
                int returnCode = client.executeMethod(method);
                method.addParameter("p", s);
                if(returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
                    System.err.println("The Post method is not implemented by this URI");
                    // still consume the response body
                    method.getResponseBodyAsString();
                } else {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
                    String readLine;
                    while(((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
                        System.err.println(readLine);
                    }
                }
                method.releaseConnection();
                method = new PostMethod("http://search.yahoo.com/search");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
            if(br != null) try { br.close(); } catch (Exception fe) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you have places where you do:

```
try{
```

and places where you do:

```
if(returnCode == HttpStatus.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED) {
```

Again, consistency. Always put a space before the opening brace, or never. I recommend always, as that is more readable.

---

And as it was mentioned in a comment:

> `for (String s in parameters)`? Is it supposed to compile?

I don't think Java supports this kind of statement. Have you tested the code?